# How to print the next crontab tasks to be executed?

Tags: cron

Is there some way to display a list of the approaching task executions? That is, translate this crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *  *   *   *     imapfilter
  4 20 *   *   Sun   fgit gc -- ~/*/ ~/.*/ ~/dev/*/
```

into this:

```
2012-04-12 14:40 imapfilter
2012-04-12 14:41 imapfilter
...
2012-04-15 20:03 imapfilter
2012-04-15 20:04 fgit gc -- ~/*/ ~/.*/ ~/dev/*/
2012-04-15 20:04 imapfilter
2012-04-15 20:05 imapfilter
...
```

It would be useful for verifying the saved schedules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I liked the idea, so I did it. It can be downloaded from [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/cronlist.git/tree).

Comment: Oh wow! And with all the options you could ever want! And it works! There will be a bounty along shortly.

Comment: [Fork](https://github.com/l0b0/cronlist) with some minor updates.